# Check out from Version Control is no longer available in Android Studio

Tags: version-control, mercurial, android-studio, git-checkout

Suddenly on my Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit PC Android Studio version 0.5.1 no longer has an "active" Check out from Version Control link on its main page. Any suggestions about how I might get that link to become active again, or what I might have done to cause it to become inactive? I can still see the link, it's just grayed-out now (and it was active a few days ago).

Note: I actually want to check out from a Mercurial repository, not Git.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about that, I discovered that somehow all of my VCS-related plugins were unchecked - I'm not sure how I did that, but after I checked them again the "Check out from Version Control" link became active again.